Dead pastor seeks revenge in gruesome ways after being deceived
This is an Indian horror movie I watched on television in 1990s. The plot is as follows:

A man (with family) wants to build a hotel. He looks for a builder. The builder (Chhagan Patel) looks for a suitable site. He finally found a suitable site. Unfortunately, it is owned by an old pastor who doesn't want the site to be built into a hotel. So the builder comes with a dirty trick (not known to the man who wants to build the hotel). He tells the pastor he wants to build an orphanage house instead. He bribes the pastor's lawyer not to tell the pastor about the plan. He presents the pastor with a contract then switches the contract at the very last moment (think of sleight-of-hand trick). The pastor signs the switched contract.
…
The pastor, upon finding out that he has been deceived (and the site is being built into a hotel – Hilltop Hotel), dies in the construction site due to heart attack.
…
Later, when the hotel has been completed, the man with his family, the builder with his foremen, and the lawyer are all trapped in the hotel due to some mysterious circumstances. It is this time the dead pastor kills everyone except the man with his family, one by one, in gruesome and mysterious ways. In the climax, the pastor kills the builder by stabbing his heart from above with something that resembles a papal staff.
…
The man finally decides to convert the hotel to an orphanage house. The pastor finally dies in peace and the movie ends.


You can answer your own questions too. Just put in the details and link to the plot on IMDb and select it as the right answer.

I've finally added my comment (answer) to the answers section... eight hours after I asked the question. Unfortunately, I can't accept it yet due to another StackExchange rule that prohibits accepting our own answer for the first 48 hours.

that is so that other users have a chance of submitting a better answer if possible

Found the movie myself. The movie's title is Hotel. Its IMDB entry is here. A full length version is available on YouTube (includes English subtitle).

The English subtitle is available here. It is not linked in the answer due to yet another StackExchange rule that prohibits users with less than 10 reputations to post answers with more than two links. I hope this comment is not blocked by yet another rule :)
